Improving local collision avoidance to navigate around large obstacles
For my collision system I’m using a boids-like method that works fine for "small" obstacles (like other characters) where the character can turn slightly left or right to avoid the obstacle depending on its direction.
This is not suitable for a large obstacle, as the behavior of the character shows it is in fact blocked trying to find an accurate direction while turning on itself.
To solve this, I have a specific routine based on the 4 corners of the obstacle, but this is limited to rectangular obstacles:

I have identified 16 possible ways to select the right corners depending on where the character come from (upper x/z, lower x/z, middle x/z) and where they want to go behind the obstacle. I made several tests based on the current velocity of the character (x and z direction on the ground only, I don’t need height at that point) to select the most suitable corners of the obstacle to reach (panel A with one corner used, and panel B with two corners used).
This solution is working well, but I would like to find an algorithm more flexible that can be used for any shaped (hexagon, octogon…) using this idea of "corners". Of course the corner positions have to be sorted in the correct order.
My collision system is AABB based in this case. If character box intersect with obstacle box then I use the corners that are precalculated to save cycles. I did not deal yet with concavities or complex shapes and my obstacles are not supposed to move or change in shape. I'm even thinking of adding some specific meshes to define the corner positions in my 3D modeller for future complex shapes...
I may have this situation where the character can cross several obstacles on its path but currently I have arranged my little world so that it can cross one after the other. My obstacle can also be flagged so that I can determine if one corner is usable or not.
For long walks I'm using AStar pathfinder based on interconnected big AABB cells to avoid long search. Each cell knows its connected neighours of course. The character knows on which cell he is walking and change it when arriving on the side limits or turn back if no neighbors on that side. Each cell has an obstacles list to speed up detection. This is why my obstacles may not move and if they do so and their cell changes they may be removed from this cell list to be added to the next one.
I know that a pathfinder could be used for my question but it requires cutting the world in small cells with various traversal costs to be effective. I did it in the past based on polygone triangles defining the world...

Are all of your obstacles convex, or do you need to deal with polygons that have concavities? Are the obstacles always far enough apart that it suffices to navigate around them one at a time, or do they ever clump up so we need to consider a cluster of obstacles to find the best route (rather than just taking the shortest path around the first obstacle which can potentially force us into a longer path around subsequent ones)? Do your obstacles move or change dynamically during play?

Thanks DM. I edited my question to answer your comments.

For a number n of corner, a simple idea was to determine the index we called START of the closest corner to the character and the index we called END of the closest corner to the target destination.
In the following piece of code Indices[10] represent 10 corners with indices 0-9.
A single for loop is used to scan clockwise from the START en counterclokwise from the END. The loop max is the number of corner. A modulo operator is used to automatically go from 9 to 0 whatever the START or END values. Each round CW and CCW are incremented. When the current loop indice match the START or END the loop stops and decreses the corresponding CW or CCW to finish with a smaller value for CW or CCW. This is used to determine the shortest number of corner to cross. This may be improve to compare not the number of corners but the distance of the path.
DWORD Indices[10];
DWORD Start = 9;
DWORD End = 0;
DWORD CCW = 0;
DWORD CW = 0;
for (DWORD n = 0; n < 10; n++) Indices[n] = n;
for (DWORD n = 0; n < 10; n++)
{
    CW++;
    CCW++;
    DWORD S = (n + Start) % 10;
    if (S == End){CW--; break;}
    S = (n + End) % 10;
    if (S == Start){ CCW--; break; }
}
if (CCW > CW)
{
    sprintf_s(buf, "Best path Start-End %d-%d in %d steps\n", Indices[Start], Indices[End], CW);
    OutputDebugStringA(buf);
}
else
if (CCW < CW)
{
    sprintf_s(buf, "Best path End-Start %d-%d in %d steps\n", Indices[End], Indices[Start], CCW);
    OutputDebugStringA(buf);
}
else
{
    sprintf_s(buf, "Same length %d steps\n", CW);
    OutputDebugStringA(buf);
}


I have added another answer that is currently in use in my AI module. I made some modifications to have it fully functionnal

This second answser is operational in my AI module. I made some modifications from the general ideas in answer 1.
DWORD2 stucture with 2 dword Start and End. I find it practical to return both values from FindClosestCorner. see below
The function GetCorners below finds the list of positions to use to turn around an obstacle given corners have been defined for this obstacle. The Corners must be defined in a clockwise order to have the function working properly. I tested still with rectangular boxes but I guess it can work with other convexe shapes.
XMFLOAT3*  GetCorners(DWORD CCount, XMFLOAT3* Corners, XMFLOAT3* pSrcPos, XMFLOAT3* pDstPos)
{
//CCount the number of corners
//Corners an array of position defining the corners
//pSrcPos is the position of the character that hits the obstacle
//pDstPos is the position where he wants to go.
//first find closest corner to the character (Start) and closest corner to the target position (End) stored in SE.start and SE.end
   DWORD2 SE = FindClosestCorner(pSrcPos, pDstPos, CCount, Corners);
   XMFLOAT3 LS[10];//array big enough to store position starting from SE.start
   XMFLOAT3 LE[10];// array big enough to store position starting from SE.end
   DWORD CCW = 0;//to increment CCW position count
   DWORD CW = 0;//to increment CW position count
   DWORD Max = 1;//at least one corner to use
   //set Start as default if only one corner to use
   LS[0] = Corners[SE.Start];
   //default pointer to used positions to the LS array if only one corner to use;
   XMFLOAT3* pOut = LS;
   //if start == end we have 1 point to go to (Max=1 pOut[0]=LS[0];
   //so don’t need to loop
   if (SE.Start != SE.End) 
   {
      LE[0] = Corners[SE.End];//set first position from End
      for (DWORD n = 0; n < CCount; n++)//loop all corner as explained previously (answer 1)
      {
        //note the +1 as we don't need to loop the Start itself
        DWORD S1 = (n + SE.Start + 1) % CCount;
        //add new position from Start. 
        //Note CW is incremented before use in LS to have the value 1 in the first 
        //round because value LS[0] is already defined
        CW++;
        LS[CW] = Corners[S1];
        //Note the + 1 as we don't need to loop the End itself      
        DWORD S2 = (n + SE.End + 1) % CCount; 
        //add new position from End. 
        //Note CCW is incremented before use in LE to have the value 1 in the first 
        //round because value LE[0] is already defined                               
        CCW++;
        LE[CCW] = Corners[S2];
        //check each round if S1 = End or S2 = start.
        //if yes set the pointer for position to use to the correct position array, 
        //update the max number of corner and decrement CW or CCW for next testing
        if (S1 == SE.End){ pOut = LS;  Max = CW + 1; CW--; break; }
        if (S2 == SE.Start){ pOut = LE; Max = CCW + 1; CCW--; break; }
      }
    }
    //create position list to use by the avoid obstacle protocol.
    XMFLOAT* pPos = new XMFLOAT3[Max];
    for (DWORD n = 0; n < Max; n++)
    {
       //if best choice is position from End we reverse the position order
       //as we have to start at the Start one.
       if ( CCW < CW ) 
          pP->pPos[n] = pOut[Max - 1 - n];
       else
          pP->pPos[n] = pOut[n];
    }
    return pPos;
}

